# Vagrant + chef-solo + berkshelf: node.js last version cookbook

Tags: node.js, vagrant, chef-solo, berkshelf

Basically, i need a working machine with node.js & npm installed.
I've configured a vagrant + berkshelf + chef enviroment, but i can't find a lastest version (>= 4.0.0) nodejs cookbook as source for my berksfile.
I've tried with this:

> https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nodejs

from chef supermarket but install a old version of node + npm.
I am experiencing for the first time vagrant and chef so i can't understand how find it.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your role or node settings you can specify default attributes for any cookbook you use. Cookbook `nodejs` allows you to set NodeJS version with the attribute `version` (check its `attributes/default.rb` file). But this attribute is taken into account only when NodeJS is installed from precompiled binaries or sources. So you need to specify `install_method` as well (default is `package`, i.e. installation via system package manager).

One more thing: you need to manually specify binary package checksum, which you can find in every release folder here: https://nodejs.org/download/release/

So, to install the latest version from official binaries use the following settings in role or node:

```
"nodejs": {
  "install_method": "binary",
  "binary": {
    "checksum": "75b029b30d4a4147d67cf75bf6e034291fb5919c6935ec23f8365cee2d463f12"
  },
  "version": "5.3.0"
}
```